# Decode regex into dictionary in Python

Tags: python, regex, json, python-2.7

I have regex string in Python string

I want to be able to decode the following string
and map them into a dictionary

But I can't figure out how to decode them out of unicode.

Is there anyway to handle this?

Thanks!

```
import json
tt = """
"mykey":"(aaa_\\d+){13})_*.*"
"""

json.loads(tt)

ttx = json.dumps(tt)
rm = json.loads(ttx)

>>> type(rm)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: don't use built-in keywords as variable names.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks Avinash

Comment: So you have a json that encodes a single string (which may be intended as a RE pattern) -- **what** "dictionary" do you expect as a result?

Comment: I want to be able to grep the regex with rm["mykey"]

Comment: Where is the source string coming from, it's not hard coded into your code like above, is it?

Comment: It's just a random regex string. Not valid pattern but still can't decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tt` is not a valid JSON string - it seems you failed to post the `ValueError` message you received when calling `json.loads(tt)`.

If you `json.dumps(tt)`, then you simply encode the whole multiline string to a JSON object that, when parsed, decodes back to a string, not a dictionary (which is why it's of `type(unicode)`).

In order to get a valid JSON string, you need to surround the "dictionary entries" by braces, and you have to escape the backslashes correctly. The following "works":

```
>>> tt = """{
... "mykey":"(aaa_\\\\d+){13})_*.*"
... }"""
>>> rm = json.loads(tt)
>>> type(rm)
<type 'dict'>
```